# Access ISP blocked website - proxy? VPN? Another way?

Tags: proxy, vpn

What i have available:
Google WiFi
Synology NAS
Docker
Nvidia Shield TV
A variety of PC's and Laptops
Private Internet Access (PIA) subscription
Very little knowledge but a 'can do' attitude!

As the title suggests, i want to be able to access an ISP blocked site on whatever device i'm on in my home network. So if i'm upstars or downstairs, on my laptop or Nvidia Shield, i can access the blocked site without any hassle.

Sure, a VPN installed on each device would work but the app on the Shield sometimes seems to bug out and my children are not old enough to fix the problem without me, so it's not route i want to go down.

I've read a little about proxy's and tunnels and pfsense and vpn routers but now i'm a little lost. If i can avoid spending any money, that would be great!

What are my options? Are there any instructions for dummies for me solutions?